# Is there more optimal way to categorize DOM other than adding class names for filtering?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am working on leaflet project, where more than 50 markers on the map need to be filtered with ~ 10 checkboxes. The filters will control the visibility of the markers.

Right now, my approach is to add a corresponding class name to each marker for each filter criteria. I am worried assigning 10 class names for more than 50 markers in the script will slow the loading time.

Here is the link 
http://jbk1109.github.io/hiking-info.html

Here is my code: the markers are created based on the geojson data, and class names are added in style function

```
<div id="distanceFilterContainer">

<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxField" class ="distanceFilter" id="short">
<label> Under 3 miles </label>

<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxField" class ="distanceFilter" id="medium">
<label> 3-8 miles </label>

<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxField" class ="distanceFilter" id="long">
<label> 8-12 miles </label>

</div>


geojson = L.geoJson(data,{
    onEachFeature: featureEvent,
    pointToLayer:function(feature, latlng){
        // console.log(latlng.lat)
        return L.circleMarker(latlng, geojsonMarkerOptions);
    },
    style: style
}).addTo(mymap)

function style(feature){
    console.log(feature)
    var length;
    if (feature.properties.Length <= 3.0){
        length = " short"
    }
    else if (feature.properties.Length > 3 && feature.properties.Length < 8)
    {
        length = " medium"
    }
    else if (feature.properties.Length >= 8.0){
        length =" long"
    }
    console.log(feature.properties.Name + length)
    return {className : feature.properties.Name + length}

}

document.getElementById("short").addEventListener("change",handleDistanceFilter)
    document.getElementById("medium").addEventListener("change",handleDistanceFilter)
    document.getElementById("long").addEventListener("change",handleDistanceFilter)

function handleDistanceFilter(e){
    var x = e.target.id
    console.log(x)
    if (!e.target.checked){
        var filtered = document.getElementsByClassName(x)
        console.log(x)
        for (var i =0; i< filtered.length; i++){
            filtered[i].classList.remove("hide")
            // filtered[i].style.visibility = 'visible';
        }
    }
    else{
        var filtered = document.getElementsByClassName(x)
        for (var i =0; i< filtered.length; i++){
            console.log(x)
            filtered[i].classList.add("hide")
            // console.log(filtered)
            // filtered[i].style.visibility = 'hidden';
        }
    }
    // console.log(e.target.checked)

}
```

Comment: This sounds like case of premature optimization.  The phrase "I am worried [X] will [hurt performance]" is future tense, implying you haven't actually found this to be the case.  [You may be right, but you also may be wrong.](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil)  Browsers are fast, and getting better.  Suggest seeing if this is an issue first.

Comment: _"I am worried assigning 10 class names for more than 50 markers in the script will slow the loading time."_ - why, any specific reason/evidence? And do you actually mean load time, or run-time performance in some way?

Comment: Run time performance - there are only 40 markers now, but it can potentially increase upto  5~600 markers.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using the `data` attribute for each rather than giving them each a distinct class, unless they need to be distinctly styled.  I don't actually know if you're taking an optimization hit, but from a maintainability standpoint, another developer might question why there are all these classes floating around.

```
element.setAttribute('data-name', x);
```

Then you could select the desired element(s) in this way:

```
document.querySelectorAll('[data-name=' + x + ']');
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So, can one "data-name" contain multiple data like class or do I need to add one "data" attribute per one datum?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want there to be too many class names in your markers, you could instead replace your style function with one that updates a hash with the key as the filter and the values being the element IDs that you want.

Example:

```
var the_hash = {"short": [], ...}
function style(feature){
    if (feature.isShort())
        the_hash["short"].push(feature);
}

function handleFilter(filter) {
    var elements = the_hash[filter];
    for (var i = 0, item; item = elements[i]; i++) {
        item.doSomething();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If I understand correctly,, the_hash will contain dataset that satisfies the criteria?

Comment: Yeah! The idea here is that the key is the property, and the array contains the list of elements described by the criteria of the key.

Answer (score 0):

With Leaflet you should avoid manipulating directly the DOM for markers, as the library still tracks the `L.circleMarker` objects and thinks they are still on map.

Instead, you should simply [`remove`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#layer-remove) them, so that the library is properly notified.

As for filtering the markers that you currently display on your map, there is also no need to resort to DOM querying, hence to have to assign some metadata classes (or dataset) beforehand to facilitate such querying.

Since you build your features through `L.geoJSON` factory and keep the resulting [GeoJSON Layer Group](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#geojson) into your `geojson` variable, you can simply use the [`eachLayer`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#layergroup-eachlayer) method on it to apply a callback function on each feature layer  previously built.

Then you can access the GeoJSON properties of each layer, as it is referenced by Leaflet in `layer.feature`.

```js
var map = L.map("map");

var geoJSONdata = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [{"type": "Feature","properties": {"Length": 8},"geometry": {"type": "Point","coordinates": [-121.7350, 46.7860]}},
  {"type": "Feature","properties": {"Length": 12},"geometry": {"type": "Point","coordinates": [-121.0750, 48.4755]}},
  {"type": "Feature","properties": {"Length": 3.2},"geometry": {"type": "Point","coordinates": [-121.8913, 46.6664]}},
  {"type": "Feature","properties": {"Length": 6.2},"geometry": {"type": "Point","coordinates": [-123.2321, 47.5066]}},
  {"type": "Feature","properties": {"Length": 8},"geometry": {"type": "Point","coordinates": [-121.6925, 48.8469]}},
  {"type": "Feature","properties": {"Length": 7.2},"geometry": {"type": "Point","coordinates": [-120.7354, 48.5162]}}]
};

L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);

var geoJSONlayerGroup = L.geoJSON(geoJSONdata, {
    onEachFeature: onEachFeature
  }).addTo(map);

map.fitBounds(geoJSONlayerGroup.getBounds());

var lengthInput = document.getElementById('length');
var lengthDisplay = document.getElementById('length2');

function filterFeatures() {
  var length = parseFloat(lengthInput.value);
  lengthDisplay.innerHTML = length;
  
  geoJSONlayerGroup.eachLayer(function (layer) {
    // Access the layer associated feature GeoJSON properties.
    if (layer.feature.properties.Length <= length) {
      layer.addTo(map); // Directly add to map, instead of using CSS classes.
    } else {
      layer.remove(); // Directly remove from map.
    }
  });
}

filterFeatures();

lengthInput.addEventListener('input', filterFeatures);

function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
  layer.bindPopup(JSON.stringify(feature.properties));
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.2.0/dist/leaflet.css">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.2.0/dist/leaflet-src.js"></script>

<input type="range" min="0" max="12" step="0.5" id="length" />
<label for="length">Max length (<span id="length2"></span>)</label>

<div id="map" style="height: 170px;"></div>
```